# Kafka Sink Connector taking time to run for the first time

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I created the source and the sink connectors below to synchronize two mysql databases, but after uploading the two connectors and perform an insertion in the source database for the first time, it takes around 5 minutes or more to reflect in the destination database. After that first insertion, subsequent changes in the source database are reflected almost immediately in the target database. What could it be?

```
name=mysql-source
connector.class=io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
tasks.max=1

database.hostname=mysql
database.port=3306
database.user=root
database.password=12345678
database.server.id=1
database.include.list=test1

topic.prefix=fullfillment

schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers=kafka:9092
schema.history.internal.kafka.topic=history.fullfillment
transforms=route
transforms.route.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter
transforms.route.regex=([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.([^.]+)
transforms.route.replacement=$3
```

```
name=mysql-sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1

connection.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/test2
connection.user=root
connection.password=12345678
auto.create=true

topics.regex=state
insert.mode=upsert
pk.mode=record_value
pk.fields=id
transforms=unwrap,createDateConverter,lastModifiedDateConverter

transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState

transforms.createDateConverter.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.createDateConverter.format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
transforms.createDateConverter.target.type=Timestamp
transforms.createDateConverter.field=created_date

transforms.lastModifiedDateConverter.type=org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.TimestampConverter$Value
transforms.lastModifiedDateConverter.format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'
transforms.lastModifiedDateConverter.target.type=Timestamp
transforms.lastModifiedDateConverter.field=last_modified_date
```